# jQuery - Alternative to chaining multiple .next() methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have a jQuery code like this:

```
$(this).next().next().next().next().html('<span>anything</span>');
```

Now I want to know is there any alternative for those `.next()` functions? *(something like `4*next()`)*

**Note:** `.nextUntil()` is not useful for me, Because I don't have any clue to use it in `.nextUntil()`. *(My HTML structure is dynamic. In other word, it is not constant. Sometimes the final element is a `span`, and sometimes it is a `div` and so on ...)*

---

**Edit:** Here is a few examples for my HTML structure:

**example1:**

```
<button>click it</button>
<div>div1</div>
<div>div2</div>
<span>span1</span>
<a>a1</a>              <!-- target !! and it should be <span>anything</span> -->
<div>div3</div>
```

**example2:**

```
<button>click it</button>
<span>span1</span>
<b>b1</b>
<span>span2</span>
<div>div1</div>       <!-- target !! and it should be <span>anything</span> -->
<div>div2</div>
<div>div3</div>
```

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef As I mentioned in the question, my HTML codes aren't identical all the time ...! So please give me a logic the same with that jQuery code.

Comment: What tells you how many `next()`'s to add?

Comment: @NickZ The number of `next()`s is constant. It is always 4 *(for example)*.

Comment: Maybe you just need some *tagret*  practice.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 boooooo

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could combine the [`.nextAll()`](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/)/[`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) methods:

```
$(this).nextAll().eq(3);
```

As a side note, the `.eq()` method accepts an index that is zero-based, which means that `.eq(3)` will select the fourth element.

#### Example:

```js
$('div.nextAll span:first').nextAll().eq(3).addClass('selected');

$('div.multipleNext span:first').next().next().next().next().addClass('selected');
```

```css
.selected {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nextAll">
  <span>1</span><span>2</span><span>3</span><span>4</span><span>5</span><span>6</span><span>7</span>
</div>

<div class="multipleNext">
  <span>1</span><span>2</span><span>3</span><span>4</span><span>5</span><span>6</span><span>7</span>
</div>
```

---

Alternatively, as pointed out in the comments, you could also use a combination of the [general sibling combinator, `~`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#general-sibling-combinators) and the [`:eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector:

```
$('~:eq(3)', this);
```

or:

```
$(this).find('~:eq(3)');
```

#### Example:

```js
$('~:eq(3)', 'div.nextAll span:first').addClass('selected');

$('div.multipleNext span:first').next().next().next().next().addClass('selected');
```

```css
.selected {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nextAll">
  <span>1</span><span>2</span><span>3</span><span>4</span><span>5</span><span>6</span><span>7</span>
</div>

<div class="multipleNext">
  <span>1</span><span>2</span><span>3</span><span>4</span><span>5</span><span>6</span><span>7</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Sounds great. Thanks. +1

Comment: @JoshCrozier Could also be achieved using next siblings selector with `:eq()`

Comment: @JoshCrozier `.find()` is not needed, could use `context` ; see post

Answer (score 2):

Could use [next siblings selector](https://api.jquery.com/next-siblings-selector/) , `:eq()` . As noted by @JoshCrozier , `.eq()` and `:eq()` are 0-based indexed

```
$("~ :eq(3)", this)
```

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $("~ :eq(3)", this).html("<span>anything</span>")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>click it</button>
<div>div1</div>
<div>div2</div>
<span>span1</span>
<a>a1</a>              <!-- target !! and it should be <span>anything</span> -->
<div>div3</div>
```